# nested html FORM is inaccessible - multiple forms problem

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

Here is the scenario, I have 3 html forms on a page and they look like

> form1() form2(form3())

a dummy program to test out the 3 forms
__

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function submitthisform(no){
    document.forms[no].submit;
}
</script>

<form action="http://cnn.com" name="1">
 <input type=submit value="cnn" onclick="submitthisform('1')" name='submit1'>
</form>

<form  action="http://google.com" name="2">

    <form  action="http://yahoo.com" name="3">
    <input type=submit value="yahoo" onclick="submitthisform('3')" name="submit3">
    </form>

<input type=submit value="google"  onclick="submitthisform('2')" name="submit2">
</form>
```

---

now when i do submit3, the onclick function gets called, where I try to submit the form3 because otherwise it always submits the form 2

in onclick, I send the form name. But form3 seems to be inaccessible. Reason is, if i traverse all the forms on the page, it doesnt return form 3 but only form 1 & 2

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
for (var i=0; i<forms.length; i++){
        alert('form'+i+' = '+forms[i].name);// displays name of form1&2 
}
```

it also gives javascript err on click submit2.

try this small code and u will get the idea. 
tell me if i can submit form 3!!!!

Comment: can you post a little more of your code? These snippets aren't terribly informative.

Answer (score 4):

According to [XHTML specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions)

> **form** must not contain other *form* elements.

So please do not do this as you can not guarantee compatibility across browsers (*current or future*)

Answer (score 0):

My solution: deactivate the parent form by moving all children into a new div. In fact, I change the form element´s type to div.

Here my code snippet tyken from a Vue.js method:

```
let target = document.createElement('div');
let source = document.getElementById(this.parentFormId); // change this!
source.parentNode.insertBefore(target,source);
source.childNodes.forEach(node => {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    target.appendChild(node);});
source.parentNode.removeChild(source);
target.id = this.parentFormId;
```

The nested form markup ist pasted in dynamically via computed property to avoid conflicts. Optionally, if the outer form needs to be restored, the form-attributes can by copied too. For my purpose, this is not necessary.

Maybe a hack, but it works well!